# Como actualizar Banderas binarias en sql server?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con SQL SERVER 2008, y para activar el bit en la posición 1 hago los siguiente:

```
UPDATE miTabla SET tratamiento=tratamiento | 1 WHERE id = @id
```

para Activar el bit 2 hago lo mismo pero le paso 2, lo que pasa ahora, es como doy de baja el bit 1 y que el 2 siga activo, muchas gracias. o si estoy mal espero me guíen, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para *apagar* un bit particular, haces una operación *and* con el bit que te interesa *apagar* en 0 y el resto en 1. Esto lo logras fácilmente negando el bit que te interesa apagar.

En concreto, para apagar el bit en la posición 1 la sintaxis sería:

```
UPDATE miTabla SET tratamiento = tratamiento & ~1 WHERE id = @id
```

Comment: la verdad no entiendo bien eso de las banderas binarias pero si funciona el código, tendré que investigar mas para que no me cueste hacer otras operaciones en un futuro.